# Maximum value of equation $ab+bc+ca$ if $a+2b+c=4$

Tags: optimization, quadratic-programming

If $a,b,c$ ${\in}$ $\mathbb{R} $ such that
$a+2b+c=4$, then find the $max$ value of
$ab+bc+ca$.

I always get stuck with max, min questions. We cannot apply AM:GM here, I have not studied much  calculus yet.
Can you do this with graphs or by plane algebra?
I don't really know what tag to put for this!

Comment: Use Lagrange Multipliers.

Comment: I don't know what this?

Comment: is. Could give a basic method?

Comment: You could potentially reduce this problem to a two variable case, perhaps it would make some things easier to see.

Comment: Maybe I will try to understand your method by watching a few videos..

Comment: How? By assuming a+b=x and b+c=y ?

Comment: Use $b=\frac{4-a-c}{2}$ to substitute in $ab+bc+ca$, then complete the squares

Answer (score 4):

Substitution of $b=\frac{4-a-c}{2}$ into $ab+bc+ca$ gives:
$$\begin{align}-\frac{a^2}{2} + 2 a -\frac{c^2}{2} + 2 c 
& = \tfrac{1}{2}\left( 4a-a^2+4c-c^2\right) \\[3pt]
& = \tfrac{1}{2}\left( 4-\left(2-a \right)^2+4-\left(2-c \right)^2 \right) \\[3pt]
& = 4-\tfrac{1}{2}\left(2-a \right)^2-\tfrac{1}{2}\left(2-c \right)^2 
\end{align}$$
And this is clearly maximal when $a=c=2$; yielding a maximal value of $4$.

Answer (score 2):

$$a+b+c=4-b$$
$$a^2+b^2+c^2+2(ab+ac+bc)=16-8b+b^2$$
$$ab+bc+ca=\frac{16-8b-a^2-c^2}2$$

Since $b=\frac{4-a-c}2$,
$$ab+bc+ca=\frac{16-16+4a+4c-a^2-c^2}2=\frac{a(4-a)+c(4-c)}2\le\frac{4+4}2=4$$

Answer (score 1):

$$f(a)=ab+c(a+b)=ab+(4-a-2b)(a+b)=-a^2+a(4-2b)+b(4-2b)$$

Once we got a quadratic function, the maximum is given by

$$f_{max}(a)=-\frac{\Delta}{4(-1)}=\frac{(4-2b)^2+4b(4-2b)}{4}=(2-b)(2+b)$$

Calling $g(b)=(2-b)(2+b)$ we see that the maximum is $4$ then $f_{max}(a)=4$.